# getNode:withName: method of soap is called more than 2 million times when parsing some big xml web service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, soap

I'm using `SudzC` as an objective-c wrapper for my xml web services, as you know, `SudzC` uses `TouchXML` which is considered one of the best and fastest xml parsers. When loading my xml web service, parsing it and finally saving it to core data, it produces around 2500 records in the database so it is kind of a big service. I noticed something weird, is `soap.m` file i placed `NSLog` statement in the following method:

```
         + (CXMLNode*) getNode: (CXMLNode*) element withName: (NSString*) name {
           for(CXMLNode* child in [element children]) {
             if([child respondsToSelector:@selector(name)] && [[child name] isEqual: name]) {
               return (CXMLNode*)child;
               }
             }

           for(CXMLNode* child in [element children]) {
             CXMLNode* el = [Soap getNode: (CXMLElement*)child withName: name];
             if(el != nil) { return el; }
               }
        return nil;
      }
```

and noticed that it's called `2,180,000` times, awesome number !!!

and the `children` method mentioned above would definitely be called the same big number too, the `children` method is defined in `CXMLNode.m` file of `TouchXML` as follows:

```
 - (NSArray *)children
      {
       NSAssert(_node != NULL, @"TODO");

       NSMutableArray *theChildren = [NSMutableArray array];
       xmlNodePtr theCurrentNode = _node->children;
   while (theCurrentNode != NULL)
    {
    CXMLNode *theNode = [CXMLNode nodeWithLibXMLNode:theCurrentNode];
    [theChildren addObject:theNode];
     theCurrentNode = theCurrentNode->next;
    }
       return(theChildren);      
   }
```

so you may imagine how much loops are going on here, however, I ran the app, and noticed that my app crashes (due to low memory) after using this web service and doing some specific actions, but if I do these specific actions (in my app) without using the web service, my app will not crash at all, giving that there is no memory leak or memory related problems in my code.
my request is to use the app with the web service without suffering from crashes..

any suggestions would be highly appreciated to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating some autoreleased objects each time through this code such as the array returned by the `children` method. These are not released until you drain the autorelease pool they are created in. Typically this is done for you the next time through the run loop. However, if create a lot of autoreleased objects inside a tight loop like it seems you are doing you will need to create your own autorelease pool inside the loop. Where makes the most sense to do this depends on the details of your code. Apple's documentation has a discussion about [using local autorelease pools to reduce peak memory footprint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html). Note, this documentation still refers to creating `NSAutoreleasePool` objects instead of the more modern `@autoreleasepool {}`.

Comment: thank you for your important hint, do you think if I put autorelease pool inside the children method, will affect the parser speed in parsing xml tags ? because the children method is a method i did not write, it is a method that is a part of TouchXML library.

Comment: by the way, I will not be able to use autorelease pool in the children method because there is nowhere to drain the pool in the method because there is a returned array.

Comment: You'd want to do it outside the children method because those arrays are likely the biggest thing building up. You'd have to restructure getNode:withName: but you can wrap most of the code in an autoreleasepool, retain whatever you want to return, exit the pool, and then autorelease your returned object in the return statement.